# Cant see managed variable names when attaching a debugger to a program when using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a program that have both C++ and C# code. If I start the program and later attaching the debugger to the process I can only see the variable names in the C++ code not the C# code.

If I start the program in debug from the beginning everything works good, but then the program runs really really slow.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Attach to Process dialog in my VS2005 has Attach to option, which is by default set to Native mode. This can be changed by clicking Select button and checking Managed option. Hopefully, VS2010 has something similar in its Attach dialog. Check Managed and Native for your application.

Comment: Even do I check the Managed option I still cant see the variable names.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the managed code.  When it breaks, *then* look at variable names.